# He never believed Peter before

Tags: past-tense, adverbs

> He never believed Peter until now.

I think it indicates a change: He begins to believe Peter now.

However, in the following sentence, is there a change implied?

> He never believed Peter before.

Comment: "He never believed Peter before - why should he start to now?"

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand your meaning.

Comment: I was giving you an example of the sentence being used when a change is _not_ implied!

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Agree with @KateBunting - neutral. Also when using "before" in this way, you'll typically want to use either the present perfect or the past perfect, depending on the situation. Simple past doesn't sound particularly natural.

Comment: To people voting to close this for "Needs more detail", please leave a comment about what details are missing.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of the two sentences are different.

"*He never believed Peter until now*" means he didn't believe Peter before, but now he does, so there's a change.

"*He never believed Peter before*" has more than one possible meaning, depending on the context. It could mean the same as the first sentence, or it could mean, "*He **has never believed** Peter before*". In this case, the simple past was used with the function: *something that started in the past and continues to now*. This is usually a function of the present perfect, but, especially in the United States, people sometimes use simple past for this meaning.